# How to list the user created table name in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I created like 20 tables in sql 11g and lost the record of them. Is there any way I can list the table names I created. 
`SELECT table_name FROM user_tables` is not the solution.

Comment: Which SQL? SQL SERVER , MySQL etc..

Comment: I guess it is oracle becuase of 11g

Comment: why SELECT table_name FROM user_tables is not the solution?

Comment: @danihip It gives you all the tables names you own(you can use). Its giving like 3000 results. n not even sure my 20 are in there.

Comment: @thejumper1337 thats the solution i was talking about. Its not right.

Comment: First, the product is called "Oracle Database" plus the Edition ( Enterprise Edition, Standard, etc.).  Not Oracle SQL Server.
  
What do you remember about these tables?  When they were created?  Column names?  
  
You need some characteristic so that you will know when you see them.
  
See: dba_objects where object_type = 'TABLE'
  
OR:  
  
dba_tab_columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best approach to solve this issue is considering the attribute of ALL_ALL_TABLES named
**LAST_ANALYZED**
It gives Date on which the table was most recently analyzed.

So you could easily query the database with the help of DATE Functions.

Answer (score 2):

First, log on as **sys** before you can view the tables in the entire database.

Second, run this query using the **sys**

```
SELECT owner, table_name FROM dba_tables WHERE owner='HR';
```

This should display all tables owned by the `HR schema`. Remember to use uppercase for the owner `(HR)` else you will receive error.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle Database Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5197.htm#REFRN26003) helps you.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_ALL_TABLES
```

Comment: Its not the answer as I told earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if user_all_tables is not your desired result, you will have to rely on dba_tables via:

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_tables
```

But for this you need more privs than for user_tables obviously

Comment: I am the only user and so the owner of my dba so this command is pretty much the same for me as I gave in the question. Both returns same results.